# Javascript automatically trigger button to submit php form with dynamic action link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm having a form with its action link created dynamically.

Basically the page is populated with pagination and the form action link is different for 1st page and last page. I have a timer running and when timeout I want the form to be submitted.

Now here is the problem. During timeout if the user is on 1st page, the javascript submit function submit with the dynamic action link created for 1st. My original purpose is to submit the form for the last page action link.

```
<form method="post" id="submitmyform" <?php if($page==$firstpage){?> action="1st/page/action/link"<?php }elseif($page==$lastpage){?>action="last/page/action/link"<?php } ?> >

  <?php if($page==$firstpage){?> 
  <input type="hidden" name="firstpagecontent1" value="somthing" >
  <input type="hidden" name="firstpagecontent2" value="somthingelse" >
  <button type="submit" id="firstpagebutton" name="firstpagebtn" value="1">
 <?php }elseif($page==$lastpage){?>
  <input type="hidden" name="lastpagecontent1" value="somthing" >
  <input type="hidden" name="lastpagecontent2" value="somthingelse" >
 <button type="submit" id="lastpagebutton" name="lastpagebtn" value="2">
 <?php } ?>
</form>
<script>
function ontimeout{ 
  var button = document.getElementById('lastpagebutton'),
  form = button.form;
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(){
    return true;
   })
}
</script>
```

I have no problem with the PHP part. I'm only trying to figure out how JS can work for me. The above JS is not working. It frequently submit but not with the last page values. Could anyone please guide me to find out where I'm stuck and possibly show a way.

Note: Above code is only illustration to give the concept. I have not included the pagination here as its long piece of code as a whole and I'm only having problem with JS.

Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function(){
  // Invoke function every 10 minutes
  $('#lastpagebutton').trigger('click');
}, 600000);
```

Using jquery

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using PHP to change the form action, until you got to the last page there is not access to the action value, meaning it won't take place in the form submit action while it is a different page than the last one.

I would suggest having that last page *url/action* in a different php variable, so it can be used as for JS expiration/redirection anytime. Something like:

**1:** Timeout - Redirection last page

```
<?php
    $lastPageUrl = 'https://example.com';
?>

<script type="application/javascript">
setTimeout(function() { timeOut() }, 3000);

function timeOut() {
    var lastPage = "<?= $lastPageUrl ?>";
    location.replace(lastPage);
}
</script>
```

**2:** Timeout - Update form action last page

```
<script type="application/javascript">

function timeOut() {
    var form = document.getElementById('submitmyform');
    form.action = '<?= $lastPageUrl ?>';
}
</script>
```

Comment: It is not posting the lastpage input values. How can i do that

Comment: Isn't `$lastpage` variable used to determine the link to the last page paginated?